# i can't see all of my targets in prometheus interface

Tags: ansible, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

i have configured prometheus and installed node exporters in my 3 azure vms but i can't see all of my vms in the prometheus interface.. i just see the node installed with prometheus

i tried to add adresses manually in my config file but still don't appear
this is my prometheus.yml

```
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
{{ prometheus_var_config | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
{% if prometheus_node_exporter_group %}
- job_name: node_exporter
  scrape_interval: 15s
  metrics_path: /metrics
static_configs:
  - targets:
{% for server in groups[prometheus_node_exporter_group] %}
    - '{{ server }}:9100'
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and this is my default file of prometheus

```
# defaults file for roles/prometheus
prometheus_dir_configuration: "/etc/prometheus"
prometheus_retention_time: "365d"
prometheus_scrape_interval: "30s"
prometheus_node_exporter: true
prometheus_node_exporter_group: "all"
prometheus_env: "production"
prometheus_var_config:
  global:
    scrape_interval: "{{ prometheus_scrape_interval }}"
    evaluation_interval: 5s
    external_labels:
      env: '{{ prometheus_env }}'
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      scrape_interval: 15s
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['{{ inventory_hostname }}:9090']
```

this is what i see: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7wd.png)

Comment: If you have a single Prometheus instance and three VMs, targets in prometheus config should contain a list of tagtets' addresses. You can see an example [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#configure-prometheus-to-monitor-the-sample-targets)

Comment: thank u @markalex it s working now